# Is there a way to change dim light to darkness?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, vision-and-light

I play a Gloomstalker whose Umbral Sight feature makes them benefit from darkness, and we're often in areas of dim light. I'd like some way to change the dim light to darkness around myself. It doesn't need to work in bright light areas.

I know about the Darkness spell, but that requires investment to see through, and more importantly, concentration which makes it quite weak. I'm looking for something else. I want just non-magical darkness.

EDIT: Is there some creature that has a sort of dark aura or similar ability? I could then check if I can summon it somehow.

Comment: @TigerGuy [Please try avoid leaving partial answers in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments).

Comment: This might be a tangential question, but how exactly fighting in darkness helps the Gloom Stalker?

Comment: @enkryptor That subclass has a feature which stops creatures relying on darkvision to see them in darkness from seeing them if they are in darkness. So they are effectively invisible to most creatures in darkness.

Comment: What is the source of the dim light?

Comment: Usually sunlight (we're in an area with lot of clouds so there id only 5hrs of dim light a day and no natural bright light) or some poor illumination inside.
Also edited the question with a new idea: there might be a creature with a way to create darkness. Then I could check if I can summon it.

Answer (score 9):

Yes with the spell [Shadow of Moil](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shadow-of-moil):

> Flame-like shadows wreathe your body until the spell ends, causing you to become heavily obscured to others. The shadows turn dim light within 10 feet of you into darkness, and bright light in the same area to dim light.

I (a warlock) use this for nice synergy with our Gloomstalker ranger.

Comment: This does have the desired effect, but its limitations as a solution for a ranger should be noted. It can be had through multiclassing into Warlock, but requires 7 levels. If the DM permits it to be added to the Ranger spell list, it remains unavailable until 13th level.

Comment: It's quite high level and requires concentration so classic warlock darkness + devil's sight is likely better but it's good to know about so thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Mundane, but: turn off the light.

Find the source of light, and take some action to remove it.

Maybe you dispel a magical source, maybe you douse a torch with water or put a upturned jug over it, maybe you put a rug over the window so the moonlight can't get in. You get the gist.

Option 2: create a shadow.

All you need for this is a bigger party member, but there are numerous other options too.

Both are available at level 1, for all classes and races.

Of course if your DM fills the world with magical dim light maybe they are hinting that this is a problem they don't want to deal with, especially if not everyone in your group has darkvision.

Comment: Wouldn't have asked if it was easy to turn off the light. Also everyone in the party has darkvision and want to fight in the dark so my previous character who didn't have darkvision and needed light was a problem. DM doesn't know I'm playing Gloom Stalker yet so they definitely aren't actively preventing it.

Comment: If the question said as much maybe I wouldn't have answered, but that doesn't invalidate this as an answer. As a low level ranger magical options aren't easy for you either, so one way or another you will be putting in effort. But finding a shadow can't be that hard can it?

Comment: I don't think a shadow within dim light is enough to count as darkness.

Comment: That is probably a question in itself to be honest, but the entire world being lit in a single type of light is really odd.